# Exception handling in Boost.Asio when io_service is threaded

Tags: c++, boost, exception, network-programming, boost-asio

If an app has only one `io_service` object and is threaded (see code below), what happens if one of the async handlers throw an exception. How does it propagate and more importantly whats the best way to handle them.

```
std::list< boost::shared_ptr< the_client > > clients_list;
for(int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
{
    clients_list.insert(boost::make_shared< the_client >( io_service, server_host, server_port ));
}

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
{
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, boost::ref(io_service)));
}

for(std::list< boost::shared_ptr< the_client > >::iterator itr = clients_list.begin(); itr != clients_list.end(); ++itr)
{
    (*itr)->connect_to_server_and_run_statemachine();
}
```

Here `the_client::connect_to_server_and_run_statemachine()` sets up the connection to server and initiates the async connection handling.

I am aware of a [question on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066557/exception-handling-in-boost-asio), but that doesn't consider the multi-threaded io_service scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing magical happens. If you catch the exception somewhere, then your `catch` block handles it. Otherwise, an uncaught exception terminates the process.

How you should handle it depends on what you want to happen. If the exception should never happen, then let it terminate the process. If you want to eat or handle the exceptions, then write a function that wraps `io_service::run` in a `try`/`catch` block and have the threads run that instead.

I don't like putting the intelligence that far from the code. My preferred solution is to never have my asynchronous functions throw exceptions unless there's a truly fatal error. If an asynchronous function knows how to handle an exception it might throw, then it should catch it.

However, it is perfectly acceptable to wrap `run` if that makes sense in your application.

Comment: Thats a bit naff, don't you think!?  [Sorry, I pressed enter by mistake] will post detailed in a minute

Comment: I'm not sure what specifically you're referring to. I discuss two approaches, and I think there are cases where both make sense.

Comment: For me the issue was that there are a few different type of client handler objects hanging off the same io_service, which I guess, makes it harder to figure out which type of client threw the exception and more crucially, what state it has left the object in. If these two are easily figured out, I can re-instantiate the object and bring the instance (replacement) back to life. .. David, I now see the edits to your answer. It makes more sense now.

Comment: If you want to catch an exception, catch it in the best place. If you're going to catch it far from where you threw it, then you'll need to bundle all kinds of context information in the exception. It is sometimes helpful for mid-level code to catch an exception thrown by low-level code and repackage a new exception for high-level code to catch. If that makes sense, do that.

Comment: @CodeMedic: I've often seen [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) used to package the context information with the exception.